# Socket.io Javascript nodejs, TCP socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, socket.io

```
I am trying to send a TCP Request to a server via IP:PORT...
```

**This code works for me:**

```
var net = require('net'); var client = new net.Socket();
const port = 1337; const HOST = "192.168.1.101";
function connect() {
  client.connect({ port: PORT, host: HOST });
  client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    client.destroy();
    });
  
    client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
    });
  }
```

**This code hangs, no response:**
(also note: I input 'http://' prior to the IP in io.connect for the response to not return the hostname as undefined (see below)):

```
console.log(socket); //returns=> undefined://192.168.1.101:1337
//uri: 'undefined//192.168.1.101:730',


const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect('192.168.1.101:1337');//=undefined hostname; works, but hangs
//const socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.101:1337'); //works, but hangs as well...

function connect() {
  console.log('connecting...');
  **socket.on('connect', () => {**
    console.log('Successfully connected!');
      // add handlers for socket events
  }); //I never receive response from socket.on('connect', ()=> {...
```

Either way I try to send a socket, I don't get a response...
it's just hanging, waiting for a response...

ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED!

```
console.log(socket); //this command returns the following response from command down below:
```

[image: socket fail undefined//192.168.1.101:1337]

<ref *1> Socket {
connected: false,
disconnected: true,
receiveBuffer: [],
sendBuffer: [],
ids: 0,
acks: {},
flags: {},
io: Manager {
nsps: { '/': [Circular *1] },
subs: [
[Function: subDestroy],
[Function: subDestroy],
[Function: subDestroy]
],
opts: {
path: '/socket.io',
hostname: '192.168.1.101',
secure: false,
port: '1337'
},
setTimeoutFn: [Function: bound setTimeout],
clearTimeoutFn: [Function: bound clearTimeout],
_reconnection: true,
_reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
_reconnectionDelay: 1000,
_reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
_randomizationFactor: 0.5,
backoff: Backoff {
ms: 1000,
max: 5000,
factor: 2,
jitter: 0.5,
attempts: 0
},
_timeout: 20000,
_readyState: 'opening',
uri: 'http://192.168.1.101:1337',
encoder: Encoder {},
decoder: Decoder {},
_autoConnect: true,
engine: Socket {
setTimeoutFn: [Function: bound setTimeout],
clearTimeoutFn: [Function: bound clearTimeout],
secure: false,
hostname: '192.168.1.101',
port: '1337',
transports: [Array],
readyState: 'opening',
writeBuffer: [],
prevBufferLen: 0,
opts: [Object],
id: null,
upgrades: null,
pingInterval: null,
pingTimeout: null,
pingTimeoutTimer: null,
transport: [XHR],
_callbacks: [Object]
},
skipReconnect: false,
_callbacks: {
'$open': [Array],
'$packet': [Array],
'$error': [Array],
'$close': [Array]
}
},
nsp: '/',
subs: [
[Function: subDestroy],
[Function: subDestroy],
[Function: subDestroy],
[Function: subDestroy]
]
}
*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare the protocol in your URL, try `http://192.168.1.101:1337` or `ws://192.168.1.101:1337` (If your server does not use SSL)

And be sure the server side also implements `socket.io` server not just TCP protocol.

Comment: Okay, I've tried the protocol: "ws://192.168.1.101:1337", but still not working.
I assume it's not working because the server is definitely not using socket.io.
I didn't know socket.io was required on the server too... is there any other method to workaround this? I'm trying to async wait for response data before continuing with code in js. Thanks! :)